# Error with shipping methods is breaking checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

I have tried all necessary debugging for getting my shipping methods to load.

Can any of you can please help me out finding a solution for solving the issue with my checkout page. After filling my billing information it was not redirecting to shipping methods. Please help me out finding a solution for this.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:47:"The user or account could not be authenticated.";i:1;s:1876:"#0 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\community\OnePica\AvaTax\lib\classes\DynamicSoapClient.class.php(35): SoapClient->__soapCall('Validate', Array, NULL, Array)
#1 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\community\OnePica\AvaTax\lib\classes\AddressServiceSoap.class.php(149): DynamicSoapClient->__call('Validate', Array)
#2 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\community\OnePica\AvaTax\lib\classes\AddressServiceSoap.class.php(149): DynamicSoapClient->Validate(Array)
#3 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\community\OnePica\AvaTax\Model\Avatax\Address.php(193): AddressServiceSoap->validate(Object(ValidateRequest))
#4 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\community\OnePica\AvaTax\Model\Sales\Quote\Address.php(85): OnePica_AvaTax_Model_Avatax_Address->validate()
#5 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php(282): OnePica_AvaTax_Model_Sales_Quote_Address->validate()
#6 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php(320): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveBilling(Array, false)
#7 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveBillingAction()
#8 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveBilling')
#9 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:30:"/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: Check if there is an error in the ajax call made after pressing "Continue".

Comment: @Marius:yes marius there is an error in the ajax call, but i am seeing that error in firefox debugger but the site is redirecting again to checkout page so i couldn't find out where the exact error is, so can you help me out finding the path of that ajax calls where i can find in the code.if you can see my site, my site is http://trulink.spacelabshealthcare.com/ .

Comment: did you check log,exception?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi yes Mr.Joshi it was showing these kind of errors.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi yes Mr.Joshi it was showing these kind of errors.2014-02-18T06:31:55+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: _catgName  in E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\design\frontend\default\spacelabs\template\custom\this-month-offer.phtml on line 68
2014-02-18T06:31:55+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only

Comment: @DushyantJoshi  :2014-02-18T06:31:55+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\design\frontend\default\spacelabs\template\callouts\left_col.phtml on line 55
2014-02-18T06:31:55+00:00 ERR (3): Strict Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference  in E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\design\frontend\default\spacelabs\template\callouts\left_col.phtml on line 55

Comment: check var/report/1344051278. paste the error

Comment: @DushyantJoshi:#4curve_shoppingcart\app\code\community\OnePica\AvaTax\Model\Sales\Quote\Address.php(85)OnePica_AvaTax_Model_Avatax_Address->validate()
#5 wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php(282): OnePica_AvaTax_Model_Sales_Quote_Address->validate()
#6 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php(320): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveBilling(Array, false)
#7 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419) Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveBillingAction()

Comment: @DushyantJoshi:#8 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveBilling')
#9 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

Comment: @DushyantJoshi:#11 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 E:\wamp\www\curve_shoppingcart\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:30:"/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

Comment: Please update your question with this report so it's more readable.

Comment: These are the errors Mr.Joshi i could'nt find out how to solve these errors very much pissed off thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Update your question with the above report as Sander Mangel said. A proper error report.

Comment: @SanderMangel: this time i have updated with all the report errors i am facing out

Comment: @DushyantJoshi: now you can see the error report clearly joshi i have updated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a 3rd party module.

Also the error message makes clear what is not working. There fails a authentication, which could come from this module as it requires:"Active AvaTax account with a company set up including applicable nexuses"

Comment: @Flyingmana: ok then i have disabled the OnePica_AvaTax module even though the issue is not resolved may be any issue with the ajax calls .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error report states **The user or account could not be authenticated**. This extension uses the service from [avalara.com](http://www.avalara.com) which requires you to have an account.

As the [installation guide](http://www.onepica.com/magento-extensions/avatax/#configuration) from Onepica indicates you need to fill out the `license key` and my best guess is that you have not filled out any/ a valid license key.
This causes a fatal error when trying to work through the checkout.

At the moment that leaves you with 2 options

1. Disable the Onepica extension via `System > Configuration > Advanced` or via the `app/etc/modules/Onepica_Avatax.xml`
2. obtain a valid license key via avalare.com and add it in the configuration in the backend

Comment: h ave done this i have disabled the onepica extension , even then also i am having the same issue, is there any issue with ajax calls from save billing.

Comment: In that case the report is not relevant to the issue. Although it might be something you want to fix if this is a production environment

Comment: @sudhir. did you flush cache after disabling the module?